Error lógico al liberar recursos de un UserControl en C#
Quisiera saber a que se debe el error lógico de mi código, estuve optimizando un código y hay una parte donde se crean controles de usuario y que son agregados a un panel, esos controles no permanecen mucho tiempo en el panel porque se limpia constantemente el panel, se crean otros y para eso antes de agregarse se limpia el Panel usando el método Clear(), el asunto es que me gustaría asegurarme que realmente el recolector haya eliminado esas instancias, aquí esta el código normal
 List<MiUserControl > listDeUserControl= new List<MiUserControl>();


    MiUserControl miusercontrol= new MiUserControl ();
    
     miusercontrol.propiedad1 = valor;
     miusercontrol.propiedad2 = xArray[i].valor;
     miusercontrol.propiedad3 = xArray[i].valor;
     miusercontrol.propiedad4 = xArray[i].valor;
     miusercontrol.propiedad5 = xArray[i].valor;
    
     listDeUserControl.Add(miusercontrol);
     panel.Controls.Add(miusercontrol);

Y Aquí usando una de la formas equivalente a implementar la infertaz IDisposable mediante using
using (MiUserControl miusercontrol= new MiUserControl ()){
 miusercontrol.propiedad1 = valor;
 miusercontrol.propiedad2 = xArray[i].valor;
 miusercontrol.propiedad3 = xArray[i].valor;
 miusercontrol.propiedad4 = xArray[i].valor;
 miusercontrol.propiedad5 = xArray[i].valor;

 listDeUserControl.Add(miusercontrol);
 panel.Controls.Add(miusercontrol);

}

Aquí es cuando tengo un error lógico porque siguiendo mediante puntos de interrupción al código compruebo que si se crea el control y se agrega al panel, pero inmediatamente se elimina, es por eso que me gustaría saber por qué sucede eso? ejemplo usando el using para archivos, el archivo no se elimina se conserva o al menos su valor se conserva, por lo que no entiendo porque sucede, pensé que era por agregar directamente el control al panel y que eso hace que se deseche la referencia, así que intenté agregar el control del listDeUserControl de esta manera
 using (MiUserControl miusercontrol= new MiUserControl ()){
 miusercontrol.propiedad1 = valor;
 miusercontrol.propiedad2 = xArray[i].valor;
 miusercontrol.propiedad3 = xArray[i].valor;
 miusercontrol.propiedad4 = xArray[i].valor;
 miusercontrol.propiedad5 = xArray[i].valor;

 listDeUserControl.Add(miusercontrol);
 panel.Controls.Add(listDeUserControl[indiceDelUserContro]);//Aqui agrego el UserControl de la lista que se agregó en la linea anterior 'listDeUserControl.Add(miusercontrol);'

}

Pero igualmente se agrega y se elimina del panel, lo cual no entiendo muy bien porque creía que List de los controles "copia" el control que se agrega y por ende aunque se deseche el original debería conservarse, o no? igual intenté agregar el control sacando la última línea que agrega el control al panel fuera del using, pero tampoco funciona, de hecho genera error. Me gustaría saber si no existe problema con los recursos al estar repitiendo esa rutina, porque el sistema cumple con una de sus funciones básicas con esa rutina de crear el UserControl,agregarlo al panel,limpiar el panel. Ayuda y gracias, lo siento por el texto.

Muestra el código de la función Disposede MiUserControl 

@Yussef El using hace que se implemente la interfaz IDisposable, no es asi? es un equivalente a tener que usar try - catch - finally con el uso del método Dispose en el bloque finally, más corto, pero igual, no? a lo que intento decir es que no es necesario llamarlo, ¿o si?

No que yo sepa. El using llama a la función dispose, de forma parecida a un finally (esta parte bien). Lo que no hace es implementar la interfaz IDisposable, y por eso te pregunto en mi primer comentario el cómo la implementaste. Además, me queda la duda que tipo de proyecto tienes, wpf???

@Yussef Muchas gracias, es un proyecto Windows Forms con el marco .Net Framework. Ya veo, en todo caso, no hay algún llamado explicito a IDisposable tanto en la clase del UserControl ni en la clase del Form donde se agregan los UserControl. No tengo mucha experiencia en programación avanzada aún, por lo que me guío de la documentación aquí lei esto y el ejemplo, https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions  en el apartado "Instrucciones try-catch y using en el control de excepciones
", gracias de nuevo.

Vamos por partes
1.- El using, lo que hace es: al finalizar el bloque llama a la función Dispose y es equivalente a:
MiUserControl miusercontrol = new MiUserControl ();
try
{
    // Algo
}
finally
{
    miusercontrol.Dispose();
}

2.- La función Dispose por sí sola no hace nada (no hay magia en el asunto). Depende estrictamente de como el desarrollador haya implementado dicha función. Por ejemplo:

Creas una clase con la interfaz IDisposable
Agregas la función Dispose y la dejas vacía
Al finalizar el using no pasará nada

3.- En tu caso tienes un control de usuario que hereda de UserControl, y en winforms el UserControl es descendiente de una multitud de clases, una de ellas es Control el cual si implementa la función Dispose, el cual limpia la memoria el objeto y lo remueve de cual panel-control del que sea parte
Entonces efectivamente, al usar using estas borrando el objeto.

4.- Por otro lado, los controles agregados al panel NO se copian, se referencian, todos los objetos en C# se pasan por referencia a menos que en el argumento de la función tenga out o ref, y no es el caso.
Por tanto, cuando haces:
public void unafuncion(){
  List<MiUserControl > listDeUserControl= new List<MiUserControl>();
  MiUserControl miusercontrol= new MiUserControl ();
  listDeUserControl.Add(miusercontrol);
  panel.Controls.Add(miusercontrol);
}

Tienes un solo objeto, no 2 ni 3. Y si el objeto estuviera presente en un millón de listas tendrías igualmente un solo objeto, y la memoria utilizada sería la misma (evidentemente sin considerar la memoria que gasta una lista)
Por otro lado, el objeto será recolectado por el GC (Garbage Collector), solo cuando deje de estar presente en todos los lados (no exista referencia a él).
En el caso del ejemplo de arriba:

Se crea una lista List<MiUserControl>: Esta lista muere cuando termina la función, no hay problema con ella
MiUserControl miusercontrol= new MiUserControl(); Esta referencia muere cuando termina la función, pero el valor se conserva ya que luego lo agregamos a un Panel
panel.Controls.Add(miusercontrol); Panel es global, por lo que no muere al finalizar la función


En conclusión:

Usar using no te aporta nada (además que te no funciona), porque realmente no estas usando memoria adicional en el objeto
Para liberar recursos, solo necesitas sacarlo del panel (mientras no tengas otra referencia a ese objeto)


Estás construyendo tu UserControl dentro de un bloque using, esto hace que cuando se salga de este bloque tu objeto se destruya y por ende todas las referencias que le cuelguen también dejan de existir. Creo que no debes construir tu control usando un bloque using, más bien deberías construir tus objetos de la siguiente forma:
List<MiUserControl > listDeUserControl= new List<MiUserControl>();
MiUserControl miusercontrol= new MiUserControl ();

miusercontrol.propiedad1 = valor;
miusercontrol.propiedad2 = xArray[i].valor;
miusercontrol.propiedad3 = xArray[i].valor;
miusercontrol.propiedad4 = xArray[i].valor;
miusercontrol.propiedad5 = xArray[i].valor;

listDeUserControl.Add(miusercontrol);
panel.Controls.Add(miusercontrol);

Y para borrar los controles que ya creaste pondrías el siguiente código en un botón de eliminar(o cualquier lugar que consideres correcto):
foreach (control in panel.Controls)
{
    if (control is MiUserControl)
    {
        control.Dispose();
    }
}

Recorres todos los controles de tu panel y si son del tipo de tu UserControl los destruyes.

Muchas gracias lo voy a probar, honestamente ya lo había pensado hacerlo o probarlo de esa manera, pero no lo quise hacer porque es un proyecto el cual tiene funciones repetitivas por lo que esta llenísimo de foreach en todas partes y además de Task para no bloquear la interfaz, y estaba pensando en eso que tu dices desde antes, pero no quiero porque no quisiera más foreach en el código no se que tan cargado pudieran ser los procesos y subprocesos, y de hecho principalmente por ello estoy buscando asegurar porque el sistema estará funcionando 24/7 24 horas(siempre). lo hago y ya les digo

@José pero es que en tu caso el using no va servir para lo que quieres hacer
